# Как сгенерировать ASCII для сетевых протоколов в консоли?

Tags: python, сеть, tcp, протоколы

Есть какая-нибудь консольная утилита, которая позволяет просматривать ASCII-диаграммы для сетевых протоколов непосредственно в консоли?

Answer (score 4):

Да, есть консольная утилита [protocol](https://github.com/luismartingarcia/protocol), написанная на [python](/questions/tagged/python), которая позволяет взглянуть на стандартные заголовки сетевых протоколов прямо в консоли, без необходимости искать информацию в [интернетах](http://www.google.com). Для установки инструмента выполните:

```
 git clone https://github.com/luismartingarcia/protocol.git
```

---

```
 сd protocol
```

---

```
sudo ./setup.py install
```

---

Собственно, всё! Проверим как работает, выполним:

```
 protocol ethernet
```

Получаем ASCII-диаграмму для ethernet:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Более подробная информация [здесь](http://www.luismg.com/protocol/).